# ceph multisite replication cannot be initialised

Tags: server, juju, ceph

We have 2 ceph clusters running on 2 different geographical locations ~2500 Km apart. The deployment is canonical charm based and is running on ubuntu 20.04 , ceph ver is octopus (15.2.7). There is a firewall between 2 clusters and we have enabled the port 80 bidirectional on the hacluster Vip for rados gateways on both clusters. we are able to telnet the port 80 between the two cluster's hacluster vip for rgw. As a part of multi-cluster zone configurations, we have created realm, zonegroup and zone on primary site , committed period and restarted RGW instances. On the secondary side we have pulled realm from master, configured default zonegroup and default realm as per master zone, created secondary zone and pulled period from master zone successfully. However during the period commit at secondary, while the command is sending secondary zone details to primary, the thread hangs and times out. logs are showing no response from master zone rgw. we are stuck at this point.

Any help would be appreciated